# Regex to match a pattern inside a for loop

Tags: regex, search

How can I create a regex that look for text `for` followed by some text and then the text `{` followed with some text and then the text `DAO.` followed with some text and then the text `}`, for example:

```
for(Entity e : list){
    e.setX(someDAO.findX(e.getId()));
}
```

Or :

```
for(Entity e : list){
   if(condition){
       someDAO.op(e.getId());
   }
}
```

This one didn't work for me :

```
\bfor\b(?s).*?DAO\.
```

But this will match any `DAO.` after a for as well as inside it, I have to be sure that I'm inside the for loop.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the number of opening '{' is bigger than the number of closing ones '}' so that exactly one more '{' exists after the for than there are '}'.

Here is a similar question: [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

The chosen answer states that this is not a regex task but there are commenters and other answers who disagree. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`\bfor\b.*\{.*DAO\..*\}` with `s`-flag. So in JavaScript it would be: `/\bfor\b.*\{.*DAO\..*\}/s`

Or without `s`-flag:

`\bfor\b.*(\{.*[\r\n]*.*)+DAO\.(.*[\r\n]*.*\})+`